# CakePHP copy file to new directory

Tags: file, cakephp, copy, cakephp-1.3

The cakephp documentation is a bit poor according the `File` api and I would like to use it to copy one file to another directory and if the directory does not exist to create it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$file = new File('your_file.ext');

if ($file->exists()) {
    $dir = new Folder('folder_inside_webroot', true);
    $file->copy($dir->path . DS . $file->name);
}
```

API about these classes:

- [Folder](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/file-folder.html#folder-api);
- [File](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/file-folder.html#file-api);

I hope it helps.